# Vuex changes not impacting modules

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have a `UserDialog` component which leverages a part of the Vuex state-tree to determine whether it should display itself or not:

```js
import { Component, Prop, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';
import { State, Getter, Mutation, Action, namespace } from 'vuex-class';
import { fk } from 'firemodel';
import { User } from '@/models/User';
const Users = namespace('users');

@Component({})
export default class UserDialog extends Vue {
  @Prop() public id!: fk;
  @Users.State public show: fk;
  @Users.Getter public selectedUser: User;
  @Users.Mutation public HIDE_USER_PROFILE: () => void;

  public get showDialog() {
    return this.show === undefined ? false : true;
  }

}
```

From the parent component I am calling Vuex's `commit('SHOW_USER_PROFILE', id)` and thereby setting this ID it *should* update the **UserDialog**'s `show` property accordingly.

[image]

I can see very clearly that the Vuex store has received the call to SHOW_USER_PROFILE and that indeed has updated the state in the state tree (this is through the Vue Developer plugin in the browser). But then when I switch over to the **UserProfile** component I see that it still has not received the state update.

> **Note:** if I reload the page (aka, CMD-R) after having set the UserID I want to highlight, it reloads the components and because I'm using `veux-persist`, the ID is still set in the state tree. At this point the component DOES receive the correct state but when relying on the normal reactivity system it just doesn't work.

Can anyone help?

---

for additional context, here are a few more modules:

**Store Definition:**:

```
export default new Vuex.Store<IRootState>({
  modules: {
    packages,
    users,
    searchCriteria,
    snackbar
  },
  plugins: [FireModelPlugin, localStorage.plugin]
});
```

**Users Mutations**:

```
const mutations: MutationTree<IUsers> = {
  selectUser(state, id: fk) {
    state.selected = id;
  },
  SHOW_USER_PROFILE(state, id: fk) {
    state.show = id;
  },
  HIDE_USER_PROFILE(state) {
    state.show = undefined;
  }
};
```

---

I have added a computed property to the `UserDialog` component above:

```
public get userId() {
  return this.$store.state.users.show;
}
```

There was a thought that maybe this would be reactive whereas the `@Users.State` decorated `show` property was not. Unfortunately, they both perform exactly the same.

[image]

Comment: Please provide all relevant code, including your vuex module

Comment: Yeah that's often quite hard when there's a larger code base but I'll try and add a bit more context now.

Comment: It looks like you aren't reactively getting the state from vuex, what you're doing is more akin to defining it once and then never again. Instead, use a `computed` property to get the vuex state reactively

Comment: My -- maybe false -- understanding was that using the `vuex-class` definition you _were_ getting a reactive property on the class. If that's not the case I feel the `Getter` decorator is a bit dangerous.

Comment: The getter should be reactive, but you're using the `this.show` instead, which is not a getter

Comment: Had you defined `show` as a computed property, it would be reactive, but instead you're fetching it once and saving that value.

Comment: Are you sure it isn't? I haven't looked at the implementation behind the decorator but my assumption is that it SHOULD become a reactive getter

Comment: Why would a `state` attribute become a getter

Comment: state and getters are 2 completely different attributes of a vuex module.

Comment: Simply because it's the only way in which the `State` decorator would be useful. Bear in mind semantics are bound to get in the way. I mean a JS getter which invokes the reactive properties of the VueJS reactivity system. I fully understand that Vuex Getters and State are different.

Comment: No, thats why you have getters, and even then, I hazard that it isn't reactive either unless you define it as a `computed` property.

Comment: I have tried your earlier suggestion of using a computed property, and it too is NOT working (in the same way). I will update the question in one sec.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174630/discussion-between-derek-and-ken).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Derek and I talked last night and realized that the cause of this problem was due to the state transitions to "undefined" which the current Reactive system does not handle (it should be fine when we get to Vue-NEXT with Object Proxies). The remaining code works just fine when I switch out the state transition from: `undefined → string → undefined` to `null → string → undefined`.

Many thanks to @Derek for spending the time.

Comment: Thanks! I had exactly the same issue and using `null` instead of `undefined` fixed it. My takeaway: avoid `undefined` when using vuex

Answer (score -2):

In the example above you're directly calling the Vuex state store. When you do this from your component this is a one time get deale. The state store is not reactive and will never tell your `computed` property that it changed.

The correct way to get the reactivity you're looking for is to implement Vuex `getters`:

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {/*...*/},
  getters: {
    show(state) {
      return state.show;
    }
  }
})
```

Then in your component:

```
computed: {
  show() {
    return this.$store.getters.show;
  }
}
```

Read more about Vuex `getters` here: https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html

Comment: That's wrong, anything inside a computed property is reactive, as long as its source data is.